# JSF ExceptionHandler removing event from queue causes NullPointer

Tags: jsf-2

We have a custom JSF2 Exception Handler ...

```
  Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
        boolean isUnHandledException = false;
        SystemException se = null;
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = (ExceptionQueuedEvent)i.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext)event.getSource();
            Throwable t = context.getException();
                    try {
                             if (apperror)
                                  take to app error page
                             if (filenotfound)
                                  take to page not found error page
                  }catch(){
                  } finally {
                    i.remove ().....causes problem....in filenot found...
..... 
                  }
```

The application exception handling works fine ,without any issues.

But the FileNotFound in our custom handler causes the issue. The exception handler catches the FileNotFound ,but while trying to remove the queuedevent i.remove it results in NullPointerException ,if i comment i.remove it works fine...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't entirely the right place to handle a `FileNotFoundException` coming from Mojarra. There's then no means of a `UIViewRoot`. Line 96 in `RenderResponsePhase` tries to do a `facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId()`, but that fails then with that NPE.

Better handle it with a servlet filter, or just with an `<error-page>` if you have a custom 404 error page.

So, *either* in the filter which is mapped on the `FacesServlet`:

```java
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, request.getRequestURI());
}
```

This will then end up in the server's default HTTP 404 error page, or any custom `<error-page>` with an `<error-code>` of 404. [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has also [such a filter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter).

*Or* in an `<error-page>` in `web.xml` matching `<exception-type>` of `FileNotFoundException`.

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.FileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```